# Can only write newlines to file

Tags: python

I have the following script:

```
import random

def mf():
    filename = raw_input("file: ")
    string="a"
    while (string):
        string = raw_input("ID\n")
        string += " | "
        string += raw_input("Title\n")
        string += " | "
        string += raw_input("Artist\n")
        string += " | "
        string += raw_input("Kind\n")
        string += " | "
        string += raw_input("Year\n")
        string += " | "
        string += raw_input("Ranking\n")
        string += " | "
        string += raw_input("Purchased\n")
        string += " | "
        string += raw_input("c\n")
        f = open(filename,'w')
        print string
        f.write(string)
        f.write("garbage")
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
        string = raw_input("...")
    n = random.randint(1,4)
    f = open(filename,'w')
    for i in range(n):
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

It writes the newlines fine, when I print the string I get what I expect, but neither "garbage" nor string is ever written.

Comment: don't call a variable `string` since it shadows the string-module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you open it again as write just after.
If you want to append to a file, use:

```
f = open(filename, "a")
```

When you open it with "w", you overwrite the current contents of the file.
But it would probably be better to just open it once and close it once.

Comment: In other words, the `"w"` option means "truncate", not just "open for writing"

Comment: Ah, thanks, it works and I feel a bit silly, I could have sworn write in python wasn't destructive.